# Building dependent deb files

Tags: package-management, dependencies, deb, packaging

I'm developing two Ubuntu packages which one depends on the other.

Say, `foo` which depends on `libfoo`.

I increment `foo` and `libfoo`'s version together. It is always the case that `foo` version `1.2.1` depends on `libfoo` version `1.2.1`.

What's the standard debian process for building `libfoo` and `foo`?

Do I have to build and install `libfoo` before and only then compile `foo`?

Can I have `pbuilder` somehow understand `foo` needs `libfoo`, and install `libfoo` before compiling `foo`?

What's the best practice for this case

Comment: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html

Comment: This is a Q & A site. I see 3 question marks here indicating 3 questions. While the questions are related, I'd prefer to see separate questions.

Comment: @ElderGeek one question with several possible solution. I need to build foo and libfoo. Neither exists. How do I build foo and automatically get libfoo. What's the standard debian process for that.

Comment: @RostislavKandilarov a guide to the debian maintainer's guide, which everyone packaging debian is familiar with is not helping. Do you have specific paragraph inside which may be related?

Comment: @fkraiem I'll be very happy if you could prove my ignorance by pointing me to where the Debian packaging guide is speaking about such case of interdependent packages. As far as I understand it is assumed that build-deps are downloaded from the debian/ubuntu repository.

Comment: @Elazar Leibovich, sorry but Owen Hines in his first comment give you a link before I specified the maintainers guide paragraph you really need. Anyway the _targets_ you're really looking for is the _Build-Depends:_ and _Depends:_ from the rule file _debian/control_.

Comment: @Elazar Leibovich, the proper chapter to read carefully from my link is [Chapter 4. Required files under the debian directory](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT on extra info in the question:**

*Pbuild* natively does what you want - just provide it with proper *dsc* file. Have a look at some real example with version in the dependences like `nmap`

```
apt-get source nmap; cat nmap_*.dsc
```

and look at the `Build-Depends` clause:

```
...
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), libgtk2.0-dev, dh-autoreconf, flex, bison, libssl-dev, libpcap0.8-dev, libpcre3-dev, binutils-dev, liblinear-dev, python (>= 2.3.5-7), python-all-dev, liblua5.2-dev
...
```

In your case you need smth like

```
Build-Depends: libfoo (=1.2.1), flex, bison, ...
```

**Original post:**

So, let us summarise the comments....

What you need are two clauses from the rule file `debian/control`:

- *Build-Depends* - dependencies of other packages for the source package build
- *Depends* -  dependencies of other packages for installation package

I strongly urge you to read the whole [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/) .Your question is addressed at [2.2. The control file](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/debian-dir-overview.html#the-control-file) . Read also the same information written by Debian team at [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html), more precisely [Chapter 5 - Control files and their fields](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html). The spent time with the manuals will pay off in saving you a lot of troubles in future if you're going to maintain deb packages in your company (or why not in Debian or Ubuntu one day :) ).

Comment: This is not the question. The problem here is, the Build-Depends I already has is not built yet, as those to packages are dependent. Whenever I  bump `foo`'s version, I bump `libfoo`. pbuilder and such would grab dependency from the repository, `libfoo` does not exist there yet.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong... then `apt-get build-dep [package-name]` or the chrooted way (in case you need different version of the OS or packages) `pbuilder build [package_dsk_file]` ?

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand something. libfoo must also be built by `pbuilder`, since, as I wrote, it is developed in tandem with foo. When `foo` is built, there's no `libfoo` to get from any repository, as both are built together. Hence adding it to `Build-Depends:` won't help by default.

Comment: @RostislavKandilarov, you are correct for separate projects, but not for packages generated by same source. I will ask the OP.

Answer (score 1):

- If those packages have separate source archives. I mean they are distinct projects. Then [Rostislav Kandilarov's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/845411/26246) is the correct one.
- Otherwise, If they are in the same source files. Then no worries, if your source compiles & installs well using `make` (`cmake` or whatever tool your using). Packaging operation comes after compiling all the source.

Quick overview of the process after calling `debuild`...etc (The exact process may override within `./debian/rules` file)

1. Cleans the tree
2. Compiles it
3. Installs it to temporary folder `./debian/tmp/`
4. Separate files to `./debian/tmp/foo/` & `./debian/tmp/libfoo/` folders.

   The binary package to be built should be declared in `./debian/control` file:

   ```
   Source: foo
   ...

   Package: foo
   ...
   Depends: libfoo (=${binary:Version}), ..
   ...

   Package: libfoo
   ...
   ```

   And the files that should be in each package in `foo.install` & `libfoo.install` respectively.
5. Files compressed to debian archives with new generated control files.

---

Let me answer your questions:

- > What's the standard debian process for building libfoo and foo?

  :/ I can't recommend those long manual to get start, but just as references  To me the best was looking to real examples:

  http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/vlc

  Do you see how many binary packages are build same source! Check at the bottom and download the `*.debian.tar.xz` archive which have all files used to package VLC.
- > Do I have to build and install libfoo before and only then compile foo?

  No. no need.
- > Can I have pbuilder somehow understand foo needs libfoo, and install libfoo before compiling foo?

  No. no need in `Build-Depends:` as it is already available in the source tree. But it needs to be included in `Depends:` of `foo` binary.